# Visual Studio 13 behaving odd with declared variables

Tags: c#

I have no idea what is going on, I am trying to connect to a database, which I have done loads of times, I have even copied code in that I know works in other projects, but VS still refuses to play ball.

example I declare a SQL connection

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");
```

I appreciate I need an actual value for it to work, but that isn't my issue I then expect to be able to specify

```
conn.Open();
```

problem is every time I type conn. I get VS put in

```
public SqlConnection Conn
    {
        get { return conn; }
        set { conn = value; }
    }
```

but Conn is still not available to me to use

if I do

```
private String myString;
```

myString is not available to me either, I have tried coding ahead anyway but VS just errors all over the place.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tried that, and rebooted for good measure.  First rule of anything computers, restart. :)

Comment: Really weird, do you have any strange add-in installed? I would try to disable them all!

Comment: are you using Resharper ?

Comment: nope, nothing.  Barely used 2013 as the current projects are 2010 and 2012 but we are doing the new project in 2013.

Comment: Is this only in 1 code file? If so, perhaps you can show us more context?

Comment: I am using resharper, totally forgot about that.  I have found some bits about suspending it and clearing the cache but I don't seem to have a cache.

Comment: As for seeing my class, other than the method decleration that is all that is in it.

Comment: If you get VS to suggest a property when typing Conn then you are not inside a method.

Comment: Thank you Dirk for making me realise my own stupidity, some how, I'm not entirely sure how, I totally forgot to put a method declaration.  Feeling pretty daft (and tired)  Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since properties are declared at the class level, the only way starting to type this:

```
conn.Open();
```

... is being turned into this (by ReSharper):

```
public SqlConnection Conn
{
    get { return conn; }
    set { conn = value; }
}
```

Would be if you're accidentally typing at the class-level, and not *inside* a method.

> but Conn is still not available to me to use

Even after the property is declared (pretending you actually created it on purpose), you still can't use `Conn` outside of a method. So the fact that it's unavailable to use means you're still typing outside of any method.

Comment: This was exactly it, Resharper being helpful and adding stupid things, only aided in confusing me rather than helping me realise my (rookie) mistake.